# Big ImageMosaic is not showing in Geoserver

Tags: image-mosaic

I have created an ImageMosaic with many big pictures, but in GeoExplorer or GeoWebCache this layer is not displayed. If i create an ImageMosaic with only 3 images (from the big ImageMosaic), then the layer displays. Why?

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: nothing, i not see any error(getserviceinfo,getMap...). Display Imagemosaic with 126 pictures, and not display with 155 pics.

Comment: http://download28.files.attachmail.ru/3480A9A25F3C41FCB9A4F9F5A17F33D7/f2d9727562731746d06b6cab45df278d/log.txt  log with errors

Answer (score 1):

the base error seems to be:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/index/quadtree/LazySearchIterator
>       at org.geotools.index.quadtree.QuadTree.search(QuadTree.java:213)
>       at org.geotools.data.shapefile.indexed.IndexedShapefileDataStore.queryQuadTree(IndexedShapefileDataStore.java:828)
>       at org.geotools.data.shapefile.indexed.IndexedShapefileDataStore.getAttributesReader(IndexedShapefileDataStore.java:532)
>       at org.geotools.data.shapefile.indexed.IndexedShapefileDataStore.getFeatureReader(IndexedShapefileDataStore.java:393)
>       at org.geotools.data.AbstractDataStore.getFeatureReader(AbstractDataStore.java:369)
>       at org.geotools.data.DefaultFeatureResults.reader(DefaultFeatureResults.java:214)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.openIterator(DataFeatureCollection.java:230)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.iterator(DataFeatureCollection.java:198)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.features(DataFeatureCollection.java:187)
>       at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.GTDataStoreGranuleCatalog.getGranules(GTDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:476)
>       ... 109 more

which would only occur if you had lost a geotools jar out of the WEB-INF directory or you have mixed two different versions together.

Are you sure you fetched the version of the plugin that matches your geoserver version?

Comment: Now i have version 3.0.2(Opengeo), but was 2.5, and i install(upgrade) opengeo only(not tools). But why working 126 pics?

Comment: I'd suspect that the quadtree is only used with more than 128 images?

Comment: I dont understand, what it mean?

Comment: if the code never tries to create a quadtree (<128 images) then this error will never occur so it might seem to be working for you with a few images

Comment: i dont understand too)), and what i must doing for more pics?

Comment: you need to fix your installation - I think you have the wrong image mosaic plugin installed

Comment: what version imagemosaic plugin must installed with opengeo 3.0.2, and how install this plugin?

Comment: if i zooming(big) then showing...

Comment: you need to raise that question with OpenGeo http://opengeo.org/support/

Comment: Unable to find property: 'format.wms.text/html' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/xml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
Unable to find property: 'format.wfs.application/gml+xml; version=3.2' for component:

Comment: "For all users of the the OpenGeo Suite Community Edition, you can use StackExchange for questions and suggestions."